# Can't run simpleLite sample of Artoolkit in Ubuntu16

Tags: linux, artoolkit

I followed the guides Artoolkit provides but it still doesn't work. Each time I execute the sample it throws me this error:

```
Using default video config.
libARvideo: GStreamer 0.10.36
Parse error: no element "videotestsrc"
setupCamera(): Unable to open connection to camera.
main(): Unable to set up AR camera.
```

I followed this tip of artoolkit here : http://artoolkit.org/documentation/doku.php?id=2_Configuration:config_video_capture_gstreamer , so I added the command :

```
v4l2src device=/dev/video0 use-fixed-fps=false ! ffmpegcolorspace ! video/x-raw-rgb,bpp=24 ! identity name=artoolkit sync=true ! fakesink
```

in ~/.profile but it still doesn't work. Any ideas?